# SurfaceDragDrop never seems to end, object seems stuck in eternal (non)manipulation

Tags: wpf, xaml, pixelsense

I'm developing a WPF application for the Surface, and have run into a bug which neither I nor my colleagues know the answer to.

I have a situation when the user can drag things from a box. The box is just an image, and when touching it, another image is spawned and is the object that gets the interaction, i.e. gets dragged and dropped. The whole dragging is performed with `SurfaceDragDrop.BeginDragDrop(...)`. Upon drop, the object simply disappears.

Now the problem is that occasionally (seems to be when input comes rapidly, just hammering the screen and not actually dragging the objects) the spawned item never despawns, i.e. it remains on screen even when input has been removed. It is possible to intereact with it by touching it to continue dragging it, but it's movement and rotation is off because it appears to think there already is another finger interacting with it.

However, through debugging I have certified that there are no touches registered to the object. It's `AreAnyTouchesCaptured` property is `false`. Manipulation is however active. So what seems to happen is that it goes into some sort of manipulation which never ends.
In order to get rid of it, I've implemented a temporary solution which simply does `SurfaceDragDrop.CancelDragDrop(..)` on such objects that have been on screen a certain period of time without any touches captured.

I hope my description of the problem is somewhat clear, if not please ask. Below is the code used to spawn the objects. I have however not written it (an ex-colleague did), I'm just stuck with the debugging:

```
private void item_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        var box = sender as Canvas;

        var imgpath = String.Format(@"[someimgpath].png");
        var bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgpath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        Image draggedItem = new Image { Source = bmp, Stretch = Stretch.None, Width = bmp.Width, Height = bmp.Height };
        draggedItem.UpdateLayout();

        var touchPoint = e.TouchDevice.GetTouchPoint(box);
        var itemX = touchPoint.Position.X - draggedItem.Width / 2.0;
        var itemY = touchPoint.Position.Y - draggedItem.Height / 2.0;

        box.Children.Add(draggedItem);

        draggedItem.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, itemX);
        draggedItem.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, itemY);
        draggedItem.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;


        //We should perfom drag-and-drop when the size of the draggedItem is updated, since
        //BeginDragDrop uses ActualWidth and ActualHeight property
        draggedItem.SizeChanged += (o, ev) =>
        {
            List<InputDevice> devices = new List<InputDevice>();
            devices.Add(e.TouchDevice);
            foreach (TouchDevice touch in box.TouchesCapturedWithin)
            {
                if (touch != e.TouchDevice)
                {
                    devices.Add(touch);
                }
            }

            var img = new Image { Source = draggedItem.Source, Stretch = Stretch.None, Width = bmp.Width, Height = bmp.Height };
            img.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, itemX);
            img.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, itemY);

            var cursor = SurfaceDragDrop.BeginDragDrop(box, draggedItem, img, draggedItem, devices, DragDropEffects.Move);
        };

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```